# PHP can't take <img> tag from page

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a problem with PHP `preg_match` function.

In CMS DLE, I try to extract a picture from the news (image-x), but in the module I'm referring to via a direct link.

```
//remove <p></p> tags
$row[$i]['short_story'] = str_replace( "</p><p>", " ",$row[$i]['short_story'] );

//remove the \" escapes (DLE put it in the MySQL column)
$row[$i]['short_story'] = str_replace("\\\"", " ", $row[$i]['short_story']);

//remove all tags except <img>, but there remains a simple text that is stored without tags
$row[$i]['img'] = strip_tags($row[$i]['short_story'], "<img>");

//try to find <img> (by '>'), to remove the simple text;
preg_match(".*>", $row[$i]['img'], $matches);

// print only <br/> (matches is empty)
print_r($matches."<br/>\n");
```

for example `print_r($row[$i]['img'])` is

```
<img src="somelink" class="fr-fic" fr-dib="" alt=""> Some text
```

And i need only

```
<img src="somelink" class="fr-fic" fr-dib="" alt="">
```

Comment: Use `/<img[^>]+>/` in pattern instead

Comment: Thank you. That helps. Mb I'm so bad in regex...

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern to selecting `<img>`  is incorrect. Use `/<img[^>]+>/` in pattern instead. The code should change to

```
preg_match("/<img[^>]+>/", $row[$i]['img'], $matches);
```

Also you can use `preg_replace()` to removing additional text after `<img>`

```
preg_replace("/(<img[^>]+>)[\w\s]+/", "$1", $string)
```